# divisors of a number java while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers

I have this Java code that I wrote for an assignment, however I used a for loop, when we were only allowed to use while loops. How would I be able to convert this to a while loop?

The intention of the code is to take the input numbers that are separated by commas, and tell how many consecutive duplicate numbers there are. i.e. `1,1` is consecutive, but `2,1,2` is not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsecDouplicates {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
String str = scan.nextLine();


String[] numbers = str.split(",");

Integer last = null;
Integer current = null;
int total = 0;

for (String number: numbers) {

  current = Integer.parseInt(number);


  if (last != null) {
    if(last == current){
      System.out.println("Duplicates: " + current);
      total = total +1;
    }
  }
  last = current;

}
System.out.println("Total duplicates: " + total);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your other logic is good then you can simply convert the `for` into `while` loop as mentioned here:

```
    int count = 0;

    while ( count < numbers.length) {

      current = Integer.parseInt(numbers[count]);


      if (last != null) {
        if(last == current){
          System.out.println("Duplicates: " + current);
          total = total +1;
        }
      }
      last = current;
      count++;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, I have a lot of issues when it comes to the logic of using while loops exclusively.